# Error: 'CupertinoPageRoute' isn't a type. Flutter (Android Studio)

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]Getting this error while running a Flutter application in android Studio:

Compiler message:
/C:/Work/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/page.dart:73:26: Error: 'CupertinoPageRoute' isn't a type.
|| (nextRoute is CupertinoPageRoute && !nextRoute.fullscreenDialog);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Work/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/page.dart:73:59: Error: The getter 'fullscreenDialog' isn't defined for the class 'TransitionRoute'.

- 'TransitionRoute' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart' ('/C:/Work/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'fullscreenDialog'.
  || (nextRoute is CupertinoPageRoute && !nextRoute.fullscreenDialog);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/Work/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/page_transitions_theme.dart:462:12: Error: The getter 'CupertinoPageRoute' isn't defined for the class 'CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder'.
- 'CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/page_transitions_theme.dart' ('/C:/Work/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/page_transitions_theme.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'CupertinoPageRoute'.
  return CupertinoPageRoute.buildPageTransitions(route, context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/Work/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/page_transitions_theme.dart:519:9: Error: The getter 'CupertinoPageRoute' isn't defined for the class 'PageTransitionsTheme'.
- 'PageTransitionsTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/page_transitions_theme.dart' ('/C:/Work/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/page_transitions_theme.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'CupertinoPageRoute'.
  if (CupertinoPageRoute.isPopGestureInProgress(route))
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/Work/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/app.dart:350:19: Error: The method 'CupertinoPageRoute' isn't defined for the class '_CupertinoAppState'.
- '_CupertinoAppState' is from 'package:flutter/src/cupertino/app.dart' ('/C:/Work/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/app.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'CupertinoPageRoute'.
  CupertinoPageRoute(settings: settings, builder: builder),
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/Work/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/nav_bar.dart:1063:25: Error: 'CupertinoPageRoute' isn't a type.
  currentRoute is CupertinoPageRoute &&
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/Work/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/nav_bar.dart:1064:22: Error: The getter 'title' isn't defined for the class 'ModalRoute'.
- 'ModalRoute' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart' ('/C:/Work/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'title'.
  currentRoute.title != null) {
  ^^^^^
  /C:/Work/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/nav_bar.dart:1065:32: Error: The getter 'title' isn't defined for the class 'ModalRoute'.
- 'ModalRoute' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart' ('/C:/Work/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/routes.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'title'.
  return Text(currentRoute.title);
  ^^^^^
  /C:/Work/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/nav_bar.dart:1451:25: Error: 'CupertinoPageRoute' isn't a type.
  } else if (route is CupertinoPageRoute && !route.isFirst) {
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/Work/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/nav_bar.dart:1452:13: Error: 'CupertinoPageRoute' isn't a type.
  final CupertinoPageRoute cupertinoRoute = route as CupertinoPageRoute;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/Work/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/nav_bar.dart:1452:67: Error: 'CupertinoPageRoute' isn't a type.
  final CupertinoPageRoute cupertinoRoute = route as CupertinoPageRoute;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/Work/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/tab_view.dart:181:14: Error: The method 'CupertinoPageRoute' isn't defined for the class '_CupertinoTabViewState'.
- '_CupertinoTabViewState' is from 'package:flutter/src/cupertino/tab_view.dart' ('/C:/Work/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/tab_view.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'CupertinoPageRoute'.
  return CupertinoPageRoute(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 0):

Run flutter clean and check all the imports.

I suggest using Material instead of Cupertino. It's my personal opinion.